# Memory Leak: TimerCallbacks objects referenced by root

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

There is a memory leak in a legacy application, so I don't know the code very well. I analyzed with MemProfiler and found out that a growing number of objects is referenced by `TimerCall` objects. These `TimerCallback`s are referenced by `_TimerCallback` objects and these are children of the root. The graph looks like `Root` -> `_TimerCallback` -> `TimerCallback` -> `MyObject`.

Since `MyObject` needs a `TimerCallback` in its constructor there are several calls like:

```
new MyObject(int timeout, new TimerCallback(SomeCallbackMethod));
```

To be honest it looks quite awkward to me to do it like this, but as I wrote it's a legacy application and it was written in "C style" C#, with lots of null assignments and `Dispose()` calls ...

So how can I remove these references to `TimerCallback` from root?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this? I do have Timer code in my app, but I'm sure I always dispose of the timers when I'm done with them, and I run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your `TimerCallback` is being used in a `Timer` object. Find out, why there are a lot of Timers active. They are likely to be the real roots keeping your callback alive.

I was just looking around the `_TimerCallback` class in **Reflector** and although I don't fully comprehend what's going on I think this class is a red herring. I think the **root cause are Timers** (maybe even disabled ones).

Comment: I did not found the solution for my memory leak yet, but it realy looks like the problem is caused by some Timer objects not beeing correctly removed, since the code contains a lot of new Timer(...) calls. The one who wrote the code was not aware of the fact that you can start and stop a Timer without the need to create a new instance each time.